# How can I print a variable size "string" in C using a for loop?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, cs50

So I started learning C last week and I'm trying to write a very simple program that prints a pyramid of # characters depending on user input (pyramid height). I was able to write a working code declaring an array with size = maximum height allowed to the user but now I want to do it without fixing the char array to a specified size, this is, I want to update the size of the array for each level of the pyramid (for each for loop passing). The program output look like this:

[image]

The code for the above image is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)

{
   int h;

   do
   {
       h = get_int("Height of Pyramid: ");
   }
   while (h < 1 || h > 8);

   char string[h*2+2];

   for (int i = 0; i < (h*2)+1; i++)
   {
       string[i] = ' ';
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
   {
       string[(h-1)-i] = '#';
       string[(h+2)+i] = '#';

       printf("%s\n",string);
   }
}
```

As you can see, every level of the pyramid has the same size. What I want to do know is: if the user input is height = 4, the first printed array (top of the pyramid) should have size=6 (2 blank spaces, 1 #, two blank spaces, 1 #) and the last printed array (the base of the pyramid) should have size 8 (3 #, two blank spaces, 3 #). From what I have readed so far I understand that I can't modify the size of an array in C, so I need to allocated memory and use pointers to make the trick, but I haven't being able to understand how to do this. Below is the code I have writed so far, is basically the same thing as the previous one but I know my array definition is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)

{
   int h;

   do
   {
       h = get_int("Height of Pyramid: ");
   }
   while (h < 1 || h > 8);

   char* string = malloc((h*2+2)*sizeof(char));

   for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
   {
       int t = 0;
       do
       {
           string[(h+2)+t] = '#';
           string[(h-1)-t] = '#';
           t++;
       }
       while (t <= i);
    
       printf("%s\n",string);
   }
   free(string);
}
```

The output of the previous code is next, and as you can see it prints a bunch of empty pyramid levels and some # characters at the base of the pyramid. I will appreciate any guide regarding how to solve this.

[image]

Comment: You never added a null terminator to `string`.

Comment: Why do you need the `string` variable? Just use nested loops to print the desired number of `#` and space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `realloc()` in the loop to increase the size of the array.

You also need to add 1 to the allocation for the string's null terminator, and then append that to the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)

{
   int h;

   do
   {
       h = get_int("Heigh of Pyramid: ");
   }
   while (h < 1 || h > 8);

   // Create initial string filled with spaces
   char* string = malloc(h + 2);
   memset(string, ' ', h+2);

   for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
   {
       string = realloc(string, h + 2 + i + 1 + 1); // + 1 because i is zero-based, + 1 for null terminator
       string[h-1-i] = '#';
       string[h+2+i] = '#';
       string[h+2+i+1] = '\0';
       printf("%s\n",string);
   }
   free(string);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this solved the problem! I don't understand perfectly how it worked but I will sit down and read your answer carefully.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int h = 7;
    char blocks[h];
    memset(blocks,'#',h);
    
    for(int i=0; i<h; ++i)
    {
        printf("%*.*s %.*s\n",h, i+1,blocks, i+1, blocks);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Output**

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4268KB
      # #
     ## ##
    ### ###
   #### ####
  ##### #####
 ###### ######
####### #######
```